# Dvorak Programmers-Qwerty ⌘

Tags: layout, keyboard, dvorak, qwerty

I've been looking into making the switch form QWERTY to DVORAK and like the concept of the Dvorak-Qwerty ⌘ keyboard layout for a mac which will leave all my apple button shortcuts the same.

However is there a version of this for the programmers Dvorak layout?

Comment: Mac OS X contains a built-in Dvorak keyboard layout. All you have to do is switch to it.

Comment: anyone find an answer for this question? Is there a Programmer's Dvorak Qwerty ⌘ layout (on OS X) ?

Comment: @CodyGray The built-in Dvorak keyboard layout is different to Programmer's Dvorak (http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/images/dvp1.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Evil mode in emacs.  You can turn on Dvorak mode just for evil-insert-state, and remain QWERTY in all other modes as well as all emacs key bindings.  I've been using it for a while trying to improving my Dvorak typing speed, but at the same time so not want to relearn all the emacs and vim keybindings.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to buy a new one just do as mentioned on this:
http://skeltoac.com/2007/10/22/apple-keyboard-aluminum-keycap-removal/

Read the installation guide for Mac osX
http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/
 http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/macosx.html

you can make your own layout with ukulele:
http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele